# What is the default Debian/Ubuntu console (TTY) font called?

Tags: fonts, debian, console, tty

I'm currently running Ubuntu and a few other Linux distributions on my computer and since I use the TTY a lot, a good font is pretty important!

Does anyone know the name of the default console/TTY font used in Ubuntu and Debian?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? 11.10 comes with a monospace variant of the Ubuntu font, but I'd be surprised if Debian used that one.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

- **Ubuntu Mono** from the Ubuntu Font Family ([font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com/)) is the default GUI monospace terminal font on Ubuntu 11.10.
- **Terminus Font** ([terminus-font.sourceforge.net](http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net)) is the default font on the Linux console (<kbd>Ctrl+Alt+F1</kbd>, `$ /bin/setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/FOO.psf.gz`)
- **GNU Unifont** ([unifoundry.com](http://unifoundry.com/unifont.html)) is the default font for the CD bootloader menu, Grub bootloader, and alternate (text-based) installer where a software framebuffer is in use. (Unifont is full-coverage fall-back font).

---

### Technical details

The GUI font is set, for Ubuntu, in the `ubuntu-artwork` package by a default setting in `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/ubuntu-artwork.gschema.override`.  The change was made in [Bug #865013](http://launchpad.net/bugs/865013) on

2011-10-04 for Ubuntu 11.10.  It's possible to query the value of this setting (the user may have overridden or changed it) with:

- `$ gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface monospace-font-name
  'Ubuntu Mono 13'`

The configuration of the Linux Terminal consoles fonts is slightly more involved; there are a limited number of slots available for characters on the framebuffer, so the best subset is selected at package install time by the code in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/console-setup.config` with the result stored in `/etc/default/console-setup`.

As @Chen Xiao-Long notes, the console font subsets are built-up from a myriad of bitmap fonts sourced from different places; these are fully documented in `/usr/share/doc/console-setup/copyright.fonts.gz`.  When the hinting-work in Ubuntu Mono reaches a high-enough level, then hopefully it will be possible to bitmaps exported from Ubuntu Mono instead, see [Bug #724022](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-font-family/+bug/724022), at least for the areas where we have coverage.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I was looking for (especially the "Technical details" section) :D

Comment: I was able to change the font size of my tty1-6 by configuring: /etc/default/console-setup which works well for mirroring a terminal from my laptop and a big-screen TV.

Comment: There is over a dozen Terminus-fonts on a standard Debian install. It would be pretty helpful to know which one exactly is the default. (especially since I changed my font but now can't find it back)

Comment: For an easy, interactive GUI-ish way to configure the TTY default font, instead of editing `/etc/default/console-setup` directly, use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`.

Comment: @rien333: I believe none of the Terminus fonts are the default. At least on Ubuntu 18.04+, it seems to be an 8x16 font from the `Fixed` familiy. You could confirm this by checking `/etc/default/console-setup` in a brand new (VM) install

Answer (score 7):

That's what I found in another post:

*"Ubuntu Monospace comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 11.10 and it is the default terminal font."*

Comment: Yes, Ubuntu Mono (http://font.ubuntu.com/) is the default GUI monospace terminal font on Ubuntu 11.10.  The Linux console (Ctrl-Alt-F1, `/bin/setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/FOO.psf.gz`) fonts are Terminus (http://terminus-font.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: @bioShark: Thanks for your answer, but what sladen posted was what I was looking fow :)

Comment: @sladen: If you repost as an answer, rather than a comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: @sladen Great info about Terminus

Comment: @sladen: Actually, after looking at the source code for the package containing the fonts (`console-setup`), only some of the fonts are Terminus. According to my `/etc/default/console-setup` file, the default font is `Fixed16`, which is made from `georgian16.bdf, unifont.bdf+h16.bdf, etl16-unicode.bdf`. Do you know where those came from? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Well, I've just figured out **the correct answer for Xubuntu 14.04** in TTY (text-only mode, no X), it's this one: `/usr/share/consolefonts/Uni2-Fixed16.psf.gz`

I've compared the default console (CTRL-ALT-F1) with modified console (CTRL-ALT-F2), where I walked through:

```
for i in /usr/share/consolefonts/Uni*; do setfont "$i"; ls -l /proc/; echo -e "\nINFO: currently set font: $i"; sleep 2; clear; done
```

(I'd been interested in unicode fonts only)

Comment: it might be also `Uni3-Fixed16.psf.gz`, I cannot see any difference between _Uni2_ and _Uni3_.

Answer (score 1):

The default terminal font in Ubuntu (19.04, etc...) is named **DejaVuSansMono** and is found in:

```
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu/DejaVuSansMono.ttf
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the [True Type (and GNU licensed) version](http://fixedsys.moviecorner.de/?l=1) of [Fixed Sys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixedsys).

It's not perfectly equal, but it's the most faithful version I've found. Take a look and enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

In my ubuntu 16.04 it's "Ubuntu Mono Regular", font size 13.

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where the fonts in every application including the Firefox browser, in my Kali, changed after I installed a file(I do not know how it changed.)

There was no perfect video/answer which showed how to reset the fonts.

1) **To change the fonts throughout the system(other than the terminal)** ,
search for the Fonts tweak tool.
Here, you can change any font that you want to use.

But if you want to use a custom font,
download a custom font(Ubuntu Regular preferably)
Then proceed as follows
**Other Locations -> Computer -> usr -> share -> fonts**.

Paste your custom font in the **fonts** folder and now you will get an option to select your custom font, in the Fonts Tweak tool.

2) If you want to reset the Terminal Font with the Default one, 
**CONSOLAS REGULAR** is the font you must download, and repeat the part 1 of this answer.

I tried a lot of fonts but nothing suits so well like this Default font.