# Is it possible to change the Terminal font?

Tags: command-line, fonts

I would like to change the font in the Terminal, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Which terminal?  Is Sublime text 2 installed on your system?

Comment: and Which font?-

Comment: Sublime text 2 is installed. The font i am interested in is the default font sublime installs with. Can't find the name of it

Comment: See also [What is the default Debian/Ubuntu console (TTY) font called?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/97469/what-is-the-default-debian-ubuntu-console-tty-font-called) and [7 Of The Best Ubuntu Terminal (Fixed Width) Fonts](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/07/7-of-best-ubuntu-terminal-fixed-width.html)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Bash terminal:

Menu, **Edit** => **Profile Preferences** => **General** tab; uncheck *Use the system fixed width font*, and select the font you want.

For general xterm terminal, you need to create a file `~/.Xresources`, and add settings to it, such as `xterm*font: Sublime\ Text\ 2-12` for 12 point (this is a guess, I don't know if it's totally correct).

Comment: My gnome-terminal crashes when I uncheck the 'use the system fixed width font' checkbox. Is there a way to modify or clear this setting without going through this GUI?

Answer (score 38):

Though you did not mention what font you are using or what terminal you are referring, I am giving a general answer to change font in gnome-terminal.

I am giving two ways to do this, though both are relatively close to each other

### Formal way

- Open the terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Then go from menu *Edit* → *Profiles*. On the profile edit window, click on the <kbd>Edit</kbd> button.
- Then in the *General* tab, uncheck *Use the system fixed width font*, and then select your desired font from dropdown menu

### Easier way

- Open the terminal with pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>.
- Right click on the terminal, from the appeared popup menu, go to *Profiles* → *Profile Preferences*
- Then in the *General* Tab, uncheck *Use the system fixed width font*, and then select your desired font from dropdown menu.

I am giving two screenshots below:

[image: Image of popup menu]

[image: Image of the "Edit" profile window]

Comment: oh wow, i didnt know it was so easy. THANK YOU!!!

Answer (score 10):

### Ubuntu 18.04 or higher

Now this setting is under

> **Edit->Preferences-> Unnamed-> Text -> Check Custom font**

[image]

Answer (score 4):

if you mean a server terminal, that is, no window system, just the console, I like [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63824/can-i-change-the-linux-console-ctrlaltf1-font-to-ubuntu-mono):

```
setfont /usr/share/consolefonts/UbuntuMono-R-8x16.psf
```

this is an example; you can see a list of available fonts like this:

```
ls /usr/share/consolefonts
```

and should you for some reason not have them, you can install them like this:

```
sudo apt-get install fonts-ubuntu-font-family-console
```

note that you may need to put the setfont command in your .profile or .bashrc as it may need to be run upon every login

Comment: As a complement: instead of putting `setfont` in `~/.profile`, you can change the default font system-wide with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup`. It will persist across reboots

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 17.04 with GNOME Terminal 3.20.2, the options are a bit different. From the menu, go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> General tab. In the `Text Appearance section`, select the `Custom font` option, click on the selected font, and then reduce the font size number at the bottom of the new window.

Comment: Yep, I use a dark theme and low brightness so the checkbox is nearly invisible

Answer (score 0):

For newcommers to this issue , it seems that you can just pick monospace fonts in gnome terminal. so if other answers wont work for you  , you could install a monospace font , then go to  `Edit -> Profile Preferences -> General` tab select your new installed monospace font. enjoy it.

See also this answer [link](https://askubuntu.com/a/1206763/1119556)

enjoy it.