# Using installed fonts in gnome-terminal

Tags: fonts, gnome-terminal

Recently I have been messing with gnome-terminal to make it look more appealing. I tried using installed fonts that were in my ~/.fonts folder (installed with Font Viewer) but when I edit the gnome-terminal profile, the installed font doesn't show up.

The font that I am trying to use is cure.se.ttf, and every other program that allows font changing works, as well as it being intstalled globally.

Am I installing them wrong, or is there a certian place they need to be?

Answer (score 7):

The configuration GUI seems to [filter non-monospace fonts](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-terminal/blob/18939a24d21d6b7c6edd57a00a3a8a48f3aecec5/src/profile-editor.c#L954-L960).

A workaround is to use `dconf` directly to set fonts:

```
# get your profile id
dconf list '/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/'
# get your current font
dconf read '/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:PROFILE_ID/font'
# set the font, make sure you include those single quotes
dconf write '/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:PROFILE_ID/font' "'FreeMono 18'"
```

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me is putting the font files in `~/.local/share/fonts` and then running,

```
$ sudo fc-cache -vf ~/.local/share/fonts
```

The fonts in `~/.local/share/fonts` are available for all apps now.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Setting font permissions resolved my problem. For example:

```
chmod 755 ~/.fonts/cure.se.ttf
```

Then open new terminal instance.

Answer (score -1):

Updating your font cache might solve the issue. Try to run the following command:

```
fc-cache -vf ~/.fonts
```

Comment: Just did again, still not working.

Comment: There is probably a better way, but what worked for me was moving the fonts to the default location on /usr/share/fonts and them update the cache again.