# Terminal text garbled

Tags: gnome-terminal

[image: Text appears garbled]

I have installed a version of GNOME after which the text in terminal appears garbled like this!

Comment: What version of GNOME is that?

Comment: Looks like the font in the terminal needs to be changed to a Mono type font like `DejaVu Sans Mono Book` or something similar.  Some fonts, like TTF fonts, can tend to overlap or space unevenly in terminal windows.

Comment: Try to change your font in the terminal for a Monospace one, to change your font read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157873/is-it-possible-to-change-the-terminal-font) for a GUI solution.

Comment: @jeremy.Snidaro changing to Monospace font solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

Change your font in the terminal for a Monospace one, to change your font read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157873/is-it-possible-to-change-the-terminal-font) for a GUI solution.

Other solution here : [why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72023/why-are-letters-overlapping-in-the-terminal)